# writing text to a pdf file

Tags: pdf, itext

I have several pdf files (about 20) and very month or so I need to change spme fields with new data. This is a very time consuming task and would like to know if there is an easy way via some sort of application where users can change the name of the variables that have to be stored into the different pdf files. This would be an enormous time saver. thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of solutions for this.. if you are willing to write some code things can get really interesting.

a simple solution would be to create a template pdf file with placeholder fields (like #{name}, #{age} etc.,), when a new pdf needs to be created using new values you can simple use itest to edit the pdf & replace the placeholders with actual values.

you can also use jasperreports for this but it would be an overkill for just 20 odd documents.

if you are interested in a sample program i'd be happy to provide you one.

Comment: Yes but that is exacltly what we are doing know. I do no longer wish to update the placeholder fields with new values. very month or so I'm losing +- 30 minutes to update the placeholder fields.

Comment: i mean to automate the update activity using a program.. the program would do the update part & you just need to provide the data saying 
`placeholder1 = abcd
placeholder2 = 35`

Answer (score 0):

If you have form fields in the PDF file then you may use [Aspose.Pdf (.NET or Java version)](http://www.aspose.com/categories/product-family-packs/aspose.pdf-product-family/default.aspx) to fill data into those fields programmatically. You can either [fill the fields](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/working-with-forms-1.html) using individual values or import the data from the XML/FDF/XFDF files etc. You can take a template PDF and save the output PDF files with different values. Please see if this might help in your scenario.

Disclosure: I work as developer evangelist at Aspose.